# Token "{", @ expected after this token in enum for processing 2.2.1

Tags: enums, syntax-error, processing

I've made a project with processing 2.2.1 and I use an enum. Howerver I called my enum Colour.java, I've got an error:

> Syntax error on token "{", @ expected after this token.

Here is my code:

```
public enum Colour
{   // --> on this line
    RED({0xFF0000, 0xDD0000, 0x990000, 0x660000, 0x330000}),
    GREEN({0x00FF00, 0x00DD00, 0x009900, 0x006600, 0x003300}),
    BLUE({0x0000FF, 0x0000DD, 0x000099, 0x000066, 0x000033});

    private final int[] shades;

    public Colour(int[] shades)
    {
        this.shades = shades;
    }

    public int[] getShades()
    {
        return shades;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for creating new int arrays needs to start with `new int[]`:

```
RED(new int[] {0xFF0000, 0xDD0000, 0x990000, 0x660000, 0x330000}),
//  ^^^^^^^^^
```

The *only* time you can omit this is when you're initializing a variable or field at the same time that you declare it:

```
int[] ints = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

After that, you will need to reduce the constructor's visibility from public to package-private or private, and then things will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use varargs

```
public enum Colour
{   // --> on this line
    RED(0xFF0000, 0xDD0000, 0x990000, 0x660000, 0x330000),
    GREEN(0x00FF00, 0x00DD00, 0x009900, 0x006600, 0x003300),
    BLUE(0x0000FF, 0x0000DD, 0x000099, 0x000066, 0x000033);

    private final int[] shades;

    Colour(int... shades)
    {
        this.shades = shades;
    }

    public int[] getShades()
    {
        return shades;
    }
}
```